# Issues sorting an array of strings in VB

Tags: vb.net

Is there a way to sort an array in VB that would put J10 and J11 after J9?

```
J1    (PN= 605848)         
J10   (PN= 605987)         
J11   (PN= 605987)         
J2    (PN= 605848)         
J3    (PN= 605836)         
J4    (PN= 605848)         
J5    (PN= 605848)         
J6    (PN= 605848)         
J7    (PN= 605189)         
J7B   (PN= 605189)         
J7E   (PN= 605189)         
J7F   (PN= 605189)         
J7I   (PN= 605189)         
J7J   (PN= 605189)         
J7M   (PN= 605189)         
J7N   (PN= 605189)         
J8    (PN= 605987)         
J9    (PN= 605987)
```

This is what I get after I run myArray.sort()

Thank you.

Comment: You didn't mention what VB version. I guess it's some .NET version. Then you could write your own comparator to do this custom sorting.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming you're using some version of VB.Net:

MicSim was right, you need to use your own Comparator. Here's how to do it.

The Comparator is any class that `inherits Comparer(Of` *something* `)`. In your case, it should inherit Comparer(Of String) because the values you want to sort are strings.

```
' If this class is frequently used, it should be in it's own source file.
' If it's used only in one place, put it at the end of that source file.

' This class is used to compare strings of the form L123
'   where L is a letter A-Z
'   and 123 is an integer
' The goal here is to make sure that "L9" comes before "L10",
' which isn't what we would get with simple string comparisons.
Class CompLetterInteger
    Inherits Comparer(Of String)
    Public Overrides Function Compare(ByVal x As String, ByVal y As String) As Integer
        ' Can value "Nothing" be in the array?
        ' This makes sure that they come at the beginning of the array.
        ' Skip these 8 lines if value Nothing is impossible.
        If x Is Nothing Then
            If y Is Nothing Then
                Return 0 ' Values sort the same
            End If
            Return -1 ' X comes before Y
        ElseIf y Is Nothing Then
            Return 1 ' Y comes before X
        End If

        ' Here we parse both arguments into the first letter,
        ' and then the numeric part. You might have to adjust
        ' this for your data - if value "J123X" is possible,
        ' you're going to have to adjust this.
        Dim x1 As String = x.Substring(0, 1)
        Dim x2 As Integer = 0
        Integer.TryParse(x.Substring(1), x2)

        Dim y1 As String = y.Substring(0, 1)
        Dim y2 As Integer = 0
        Integer.TryParse(y.Substring(1), y2)

        ' Now decide which value should come first.
        ' -1 means that X should come first,
        ' +1 means that Y should come first,
        '  0 means that they sort the same.
        If x1 < y1 Then Return -1 ' The letter of X is before the letter of Y
        If x1 > y1 Then Return 1 ' The letter of X is after the letter of Y
        ' The letters are equal, so look at the numeric part
        If x2 < y2 Then Return -1 ' The number of X is less than the number of Y
        If x2 > y2 Then Return 1 ' The number of X is more than the number of Y
        Return 0    ' The two strings sort the same
        ' Note that this does not mean that the two strings are identical.
        ' "Y99" would sort the same as "Y099",
        ' because the letters are the same and the numbers are the same value.
    End Function
End Class
```

To actually sort the array:

```
Dim Arr() As String = {"J1", "J9", "J10", "J11"} ' Etc.
Array.Sort(Arr, New CompLetterInteger)
```